# Custom linked list data printing backword

Tags: java, data-structures

I just created my custom node class and created a linked list, but when I print the data in my list the data is printed backward.  I thought I set the pointers right and adding new node at the beginning of the list.  But apparently the  compiler thinks otherwise. It took me a while to finally understand pointers but I guess I didn't understand as well as I thought.

```
public class Node {

public String data;
public String cat; 
public Node next; 

public Node (String data, String cat, Node next){
    this.data=data; 
    this.cat=cat; 
    this.next=next; 
}

public Node() {

}
public String toString()
{
    return "Patient: " + data + "   Category: " +cat ; 
}
```

}

---

```
public class Main {

public static Node head; 
public static void main (String args [])
{
    add("P1" , "2"); 
    add("P2", "3"); 
    add("P3", "4"); 
    add("P4", "4"); 
printList(); 
}

// add data to nodes

public  static void add(String d, String c)
{
    Node temp = null; 

    if (head == null)
    {
        head = new Node(d, c, null); 
    }
    else
    {
        temp=head; 
        head= new Node(d, c, temp); 
    }

}
// print node data

public static void printList()
{
    while (head != null)
    {
        System.out.println(head); 
        head=head.next;      
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you need to add to the list from a tail pointer. If you only use a head pointer, it will behave like a stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list is printing out backwards because later nodes created are placed at the head of the list, instead of at the back.  I.E.

```
head -> Node1
```

becomes

```
head -> Node2 -> Node1
```

and then

```
head -> Node3 -> Node2 -> Node1
```

Your iteration in `printList` is okay.  In `add`, instead of placing the new `Node` at the head, you'll need to find the last `Node` (with `next` being `null`) and place the new `Node` there.  I.e.

```
head -> Node1
```

becomes

```
head -> Node1 -> Node2
```

Change your `else` (for when the list isn't empty) to:

```
else
{
    temp = head;
    // Get last item
    while (temp.next != null)
    {
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    // Point old last item to *new* last item
    temp.next = new Node(d, c, null); 
}
```

Comment: @bimm3rBoy I added code to my answer to add to the end of the list.

Comment: Thanks I finally got it!

Answer (score 0):

rgettman is right, when you add an element to the linked list you add in the first position

```
//element1->null
//add(element2)
//element2->element1->null
```

you can do a iteration searching for null and insert in the last position, something like this

```
public  static void add(String d, String c)
{
    Node temp = null; 

    if (head == null)
    {
        head = new Node(d, c, null); 
    }
    else
    { 
        temp=head;
        while(temp!=null){ //search last element
            temp=temp.next();
        }
        temp.next= new Node(d, c, null); //the new element it's after the last
    }

}
```

You can also create a variable called Node lastNode and save here the last node, doing this you don't have to loop, more efficient algorithm. something like:

```
public class Node {
    public Node lastNode;
...
}
```

and in Main class...

```
public  static void add(String d, String c)

{
    Node temp = null; 

    if (head == null)
    {
        head = new Node(d, c, null); 
        lastNode=head;
    }
    else
    { 
        Node newnode= new Node(d,c,null);
        lastNode.next=newnode;
        lastNode= newnode;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're describing is actually exactly how a LinkedList is expected to work. Like rgettman pointed out, when you use the add method on a LinkedList, you add to the head of the list. The thing is, when you remove from the LinkedList by setting head = head.next, you ALSO remove from the head.

If it's still not clear, check out this animation: http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/StackLL.html Try pushing a few integers to the stack, and then popping them. This is how your linked list is working.

One way to fix this would be to stick all the values together so that you put them in order before printing them.

```
public static void printList()
{
    String toPrint = "";
    while (head != null)
    {
        toPrint = head + "\n" + toPrint; 
        head = head.next;      
    }
    System.out.println(toPrint);
}
```